# Rails Lib files loading error

Tags: file, ruby-on-rails-3, liquid

In my project I'm using some custom liquid tags and I have created a folder called 'Liquid' inside my 'lib' directory and there I have a liquid module called helpers,

```
module  Liquid::Helpers

end
```

So the project tree is as follows

Root

```
--> lib 

      --> Liquid
```

And I'm trying to register my tags in my environment.rb file

```
Liquid::Template.register_filter(Liquid::Helpers)
```

To load my lib files when the server starts, I'm trying this in application.rb

```
config.autoload_paths <<  File.join(Rails.root.to_s, "lib")
```

But I'm getting the following error

': uninitialized constant Liquid::Helpers (NameError)

What am i missing here, can someone help me, thanks in advance

cheers

sameera

Update -

I'm on Rails3 with Ubuntu. Following is my full error code

```
`<top (required)>': uninitialized constant Liquid::Helpers (NameError)
    from <project path>/config.ru:3:in `require'
    from <project path>/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `instance_eval'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `initialize'
    from <project path>/config.ru:1:in `new'
    from <project path>/config.ru:1:in `<main>'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:35:in `eval'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:35:in `parse_file'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/server.rb:162:in `app'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/server.rb:248:in `wrapped_app'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/server.rb:213:in `start'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:65:in `start'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:30:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:27:in `tap'
    from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:27:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a high enough level yet to ask clarifying questions, but my first piece of advice is to clarify your question in the following way (consider this solid advice for posting any question anywhere):

- list the versions of rails, liquid, gems, ruby, etc that you are using (especially the rails version)
- copy-paste the entire output of your terminal where the error message is arising.  While you may not understand that output, it is useful for someone else to debug your situation.  Copy-pasting from the terminal (including the command you ran) leaves zero question
- provide better info on your file structure.  Once again a terminal copy-paste is perfect.  From your rails root, you could run the command `find lib` (unless you're on Windows, in which case you can't use find and it's time to consider switching to OSX or ubuntu).

Here's an example of a terminal copy-paste that includes all that information:

```
dhcp-c-200:foo luke$ rails -v && gem -v && ruby -v && gem list | grep liquid
Rails 2.3.5
1.3.5
ruby 1.8.7 (2009-06-12 patchlevel 174) [universal-darwin10.0]
dhcp-c-200:foo luke$ find lib
lib
lib/Liquid
lib/Liquid/some_module_file.rb
lib/tasks
dhcp-c-200:foo luke$ script/server
=> Booting Mongrel
=> Rails 2.3.5 application starting on http://0.0.0.0:3000
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:440:in `load_missing_constant': uninitialized constant Liquid::Template (NameError)
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:80:in `const_missing'
    from /Users/luke/Sites/foo/config/environment.rb:43
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:521:in `new_constants_in'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:156:in `require'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/commands/server.rb:84
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
    from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
    from script/server:3
dhcp-c-200:foo luke$ cat lib/Liquid/some_module_file.rb 
module Liquid

end

module Liquid::Foo

enddhcp-c-200:foo luke$
```

... all in one terminal.